# Replace specific text in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, wpf, replace

I'm trying to implement a solution to remove a URL from a textbox and replace it with ""

So something like this:

> "Hey check out this site http://www.anywhere.com"

Would become:

> "Hey check out this site <URL Quarantined>"

This is what I've got at the moment but I don't think I'm doing this correctly, any help would be really appreciated! :)

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtContent.Text.Contains("http:"))
    {
        txtContent.Text.Replace("http", "<URL Quarrantined>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the modified text txtContent.Text = txtContent.Text.Replace("http", "<URL Quarrantined>");

Comment: In contrast to some other programming languages, the C# string replace does not modify the original string, but leaves the original string unchanged and has the modified string as the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is only replacing "http", of course. If you want to replace the whole URL you will have to resort to regular expressions like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?");
txtContent.Text = regex.Replace(txtContent.Text, "<URL Quarrantined>");
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work I'm afraid the text remains unchanged. Would it be best to implement an if statement something like: if(regex.Is.Match(txtContent.Text)?

Comment: No. If there is nothing to replace, the text remains unchanged anyway.

Comment: What kind of Control is txtContent?

Comment: Sorry, it's a textbox

Comment: I just tried it with a simple WPF application and it worked just fine. Do you use DataBinding with this TextBox? In that case you might need to change the property the TextBox' Text value is bound to.

Comment: Thanks! That's been really helpful. I'm doing the below in another button to iterate through a list of messages. When I comment it out the URLs are removed so think I'll have to change this around: txtContent.Text = messageContent[index];

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of "http" and create a new string:

```
static string Convert(string s)
{
    const string t = "<URL Quarantined>";
    int index = s.LastIndexOf("http");
    if (index != -1)
        return string.Concat(s.AsSpan().Slice(0, s.Length - index + 1), t);

    return s;
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = Convert("Hey check out this site http://www.anywhere.com");
```

Or:

```
txtContent.Text = Convert(txtContent.Text);
```

The .NET Framework `Substring` version allocates an additional string:

```
static string Convert(string s)
{
    const string t = "<URL Quarantined>";
    int index = s.LastIndexOf("http");
    if (index != -1)
        return string.Concat(s.Substring(0, s.Length - index + 1), t);

    return s;
}
```